# JS/Jest: how to mock a simple function to remove an event listener

Tags: javascript, jestjs, video.js

I am using `video.js` and have code that uses `on` listener for on `play` and fires a `getNames` callback.  At the end of that, I call `video.off` and pass in `play` and `getNames` .  I saw in the docs that this is the proper way to have an event fire once and then remove it from happening again.  My issue is mocking `video.off` in my test file though.

**code.js**

```
video.on('play', function getNames() {
  
    // do stuff    

    video.off('play', getNames);
});
```

Below, I have my `video.on` mocked where it fires a callback when the event is `play`.

**code.test.js**

```
video.on = mockOn;

const mockOn = jest.fn().mockImplementation((event, callback) => {
  if (event === 'play') {
    callback();
  }
}),
```

What would `video.off` look like though?  Would it just be as simple as `video.off = jest.fn()` since it's not firing a callback like the `on` is?

Comment: Did you try doing your suggestion? What happened?

Comment: Your interpretation for your question looks fine by me.

Comment: Video.js has a one time event listener which wouldn't need `off`: `video.one('play', ...`

Comment: oh thanks @misterben , didn't know that!